# How to make a function with dynamic variables to add rows in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, function

I'm trying to make a table from a list of data using pandas.

Originally I wanted to make a function where I can pass dynamic variables so I could continuously add new rows from data list.

It works up until a point where adding rows part begun. Column headers are adding, but the data - no. It either keeps value at only last col or adds nothing.

My scrath was:

```
for title in titles:
   for x in data:
      table = {
        title: data[x]
}
df.DataFrame(table, columns=titles, index[0]
```

columns list:

```
titles = ['timestamp', 'source', 'tracepoint']
```

data list:

```
data = ['first', 'second', 'third',
        'first', 'second', 'third',
        'first', 'second', 'third']
```

How can I make something like this?

```
timestamp, source, tracepoint
first, second, third
first, second, third
first, second, third
```

Comment: Instead of loop, I suggest you to use numpy and reshape the data by using reshape function. Then you won't need loop, you'll just put the shaped array and you can put it to pd.DataFrame with the columns

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([data[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(data), 3)], columns=titles)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to initialize pandas dataframe, you can use dataframe’s constructor.
And you can also append row by using a dict.
Pandas provides other useful functions,
such as concatenation between data frames, insert/delete columns. If you need, please check pandas’s doc.

```py
import pandas as pd

# initialization by dataframe’s constructor
titles = ['timestamp', 'source', 'tracepoint']
data = [['first', 'second', 'third'],
        ['first', 'second', 'third'],
        ['first', 'second', 'third']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=titles)
print('---initialization---')
print(df)

# append row
new_row = {
    'timestamp': '2020/11/01',
    'source': 'xxx',
    'tracepoint': 'yyy'
}
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
print('---append result---')
print(df)
```

output

```
---initialization---
  timestamp  source tracepoint
0     first  second      third
1     first  second      third
2     first  second      third
---append result---
    timestamp  source tracepoint
0       first  second      third
1       first  second      third
2       first  second      third
3  2020/11/01     xxx        yyy
```